# Recursive SQL query (parent-child) to include total downline records per record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I have a table that has a parent - child structure.

I managed to bring this structure sorted by creating a field called "Path" with the first name of the agent, so this query:

```
  WITH cte(PLID, sponsorid, firstname, lastname, Status, LEVEL, path) AS (SELECT
                            PLID, sponsorid, firstname, lastname, Status, 0 AS LEVEL, CAST(firstname AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS path
                            FROM TEST  WHERE PLID =1  UNION ALL
                            SELECT c.PLID, c.sponsorid, c.firstname, c.lastname, c.Status, cte. LEVEL + 1 AS LEVEL,
                            CAST((cte.path + '/' + c.firstname) AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
                            AS path FROM TEST c INNER JOIN cte ON c.sponsorid = cte.plid)
                            SELECT PLID, sponsorid, firstname, lastname, Status, LEVEL, path
                            FROM cte ORDER BY path ASC
```

...returns this, the treeview data:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| PLID | SPONSORID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | STATUS | LEVEL |                PATH                 |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------+
|    1 |         0 | Danielle  | Lipsin   |      1 |     0 | Danielle                            |
|    4 |         1 | Alissa    | Doe      |      1 |     1 | Danielle/Alissa                     |
|    2 |         1 | Charles   | Doe      |      1 |     1 | Danielle/Charles                    |
|    6 |         2 | Mark      | Doe      |      1 |     2 | Danielle/Charles/Mark               |
|    5 |         2 | Martin    | Doe      |      1 |     2 | Danielle/Charles/Martin             |
|    8 |         5 | Katy      | Perry    |      1 |     3 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Katy        |
|    7 |         5 | Leo       | Messi    |      1 |     3 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Leo         |
|    9 |         7 | Alex      | Doe      |      1 |     4 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Leo/Alex    |
|   10 |         7 | Laureen   | Doe      |      1 |     4 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Leo/Laureen |
|    3 |         1 | Michelle  | Doe      |      1 |     1 | Danielle/Michelle                   |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------+
```

I tried to do a nested select but it didn't work. What is the best approach to include the total number of children on each record?

Expected Results:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------+---------------+
| PLID | SPONSORID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | STATUS | LEVEL |                PATH                 | TotalDownline |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------+---------------+
|    1 |         0 | Danielle  | Lipsin   |      1 |     0 | Danielle                            |             9 |
|    4 |         1 | Alissa    | Doe      |      1 |     1 | Danielle/Alissa                     |             0 |
|    2 |         1 | Charles   | Doe      |      1 |     1 | Danielle/Charles                    |             7 |
|    6 |         2 | Mark      | Doe      |      1 |     2 | Danielle/Charles/Mark               |             0 |
|    5 |         2 | Martin    | Doe      |      1 |     2 | Danielle/Charles/Martin             |             4 |
|    8 |         5 | Katy      | Perry    |      1 |     3 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Katy        |             0 |
|    7 |         5 | Leo       | Messi    |      1 |     3 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Leo         |             2 |
|    9 |         7 | Alex      | Doe      |      1 |     4 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Leo/Alex    |             0 |
|   10 |         7 | Laureen   | Doe      |      1 |     4 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Leo/Laureen |             0 |
|    3 |         1 | Michelle  | Doe      |      1 |     1 | Danielle/Michelle                   |             0 |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    PLID int,
    sponsorid int,
    firstname nvarchar(50),
    lastname nvarchar(50),
    status int
);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1,0,'Danielle', 'Lipsin', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2,1,'Charles', 'Doe', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (3,1,'Michelle', 'Doe', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (4,1,'Alissa', 'Doe', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (5,2,'Martin', 'Doe', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (6,2,'Mark', 'Doe', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (7,5,'Leo', 'Messi', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (8,5,'Katy', 'Perry', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (9,7,'Alex', 'Doe', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (10,7,'Laureen', 'Doe', 1);
```

Comment: Hi Dale. Do you want me to delete the image then? Allow me a few minutes so I can do it nice. Thanks.

Comment: Done, Dale :) Have a great one.

Comment: Please provide queries to create the table and insert some sample data. In addition we need the expected result set **According to the sample data**.

Comment: Not really Dale, because in that example they are querying a second table (sales) where I should do a recursive query per record, to get the total downline per agent on the very same table (a recursive count of a recursive table) and that's where Im struggling with. In other words, I not only need the count of the records for the direct downline, but also the downline of the downline. I don't know if Im clear explaining it. I thought about making a loop and a new query per record, but that will crash the server (25,000+ agents).

Comment: Im on it Dale. Sorry, trying to get this Q right while dealing with my boss. Im on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, one possible way you could do it, not at all sure its the best way though.

1. Create a new column `pathid` based on the same principle as your existing `path` (name), but being unique per person.
2. Count how many times that `id` shows up in `pathid` other than ours by using a sub-query against the CTE.

```
WITH cte1 (PLID, sponsorid, firstname, lastname, [Status], [LEVEL], [path], pathid) AS (
    SELECT PLID, sponsorid, firstname, lastname, [Status], 0 AS [LEVEL]
      , CAST(firstname AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS [path]
      , CAST('/' + CAST(PLID AS varchar(38)) AS varchar(max)) AS pathid
    FROM #TEST
    WHERE PLID = 1--94
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.PLID, c.sponsorid, c.firstname, c.lastname, c.[Status], cte1.[LEVEL] + 1 AS [LEVEL]
      , CAST((cte1.[path] + '/' + c.firstname) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS [path]
      , CAST(cte1.pathid + '/' + cast(c.PLID AS varchar(38)) AS varchar(max)) AS pathid
    FROM #TEST c
    INNER JOIN cte1 ON c.sponsorid = cte1.plid
)
SELECT PLID, sponsorid, firstname, lastname, [Status], [LEVEL], [path], pathid
    , (select count(*) from cte1 B where B.pathid + '/' like '%/' + cast(A.PLID AS varchar(38)) + '/%' and B.PLID <> A.PLID)
FROM cte1 A
ORDER BY [path] ASC;
```

Returns for your sample data:

| PLID | sponsorid | firstname | lastname | Status | LEVEL | path | pathid | Total Downline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Danielle | Lipsin | 1 | 0 | Danielle | /1 | 9 |
| 4 | 1 | Alissa | Doe | 1 | 1 | Danielle/Alissa | /1/4 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | Charles | Doe | 1 | 1 | Danielle/Charles | /1/2 | 6 |
| 6 | 2 | Mark | Doe | 1 | 2 | Danielle/Charles/Mark | /1/2/6 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | Martin | Doe | 1 | 2 | Danielle/Charles/Martin | /1/2/5 | 4 |
| 8 | 5 | Katy | Perry | 1 | 3 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Katy | /1/2/5/8 | 0 |
| 7 | 5 | Leo | Messi | 1 | 3 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Leo | /1/2/5/7 | 2 |
| 9 | 7 | Alex | Doe | 1 | 4 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Leo/Alex | /1/2/5/7/9 | 0 |
| 10 | 7 | Laureen | Doe | 1 | 4 | Danielle/Charles/Martin/Leo/Laureen | /1/2/5/7/10 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | Michelle | Doe | 1 | 1 | Danielle/Michelle | /1/3 | 0 |

Comment: Im trying to understand the query first Dale. Im gonna try it in a few minutes. I want to understand it first. Thanks.

Comment: It works perfect, but Im trying to understand how did you got it done lol. Thanks Dale.

Comment: You can see what its doing on the path column better because you can see the name - you just can't use that because name will never be unique. So if you take "Charles" ("Danielle" is too obvious), then its ignoring itself and counting how many other rows have "Charles" in the path column (and of course its using ID not name). Its fairly obvious that Charles appears 6 more times after themselves. And it does this for every row - so it won't perform well, its having to do a sub-query for every row.

Comment: Wow that is clever. I get it now. Thanks so much for this, I was struggling for almost two days on this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Dale, the query takes less than 2 seconds to process 25,492 records. That is awesome.

Comment: @Danielle good to hear :)